# Web Crawling Conversion Rates and Graphing Them

Tags: php, sql, web-crawler, currency, roblox

I've come to need a way of tracking and recording conversion rates of a fake currency on [Roblox](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+roblox). I think javascript is suitable for the tracking part, however, I'd like to also record that data in a spreadsheet and create a refreshing graph as the data comes in. The resolution of the graph will be at most of 5 second intervals. If you take a look at the Roblox conversion page below, you can see the current positions made by other people to trade their robux or tix to robux or tix. The page displays the top trading positions made by others. I only want to track the conversion rates at the top of each column as shown on the trade currency page.

If I were to create a program locally stored on my computer, what language(s)/program(s) should I use to accomplish this? Also, if I were to host a server (Using my raspberry pi or free hosting service), what language(s)/script(s) should I use to accomplish this? Lastly, if I were to make this an online thing (With my R-Pi or free hosting), I would like to access the graph through a browser, either on my network or on the internet (Which I've done before when creating a website for my R-Pi).

Thank you for your time in reading,
Cameron

[Link to the conversion rate page](http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx#/#TradeCurrency_tab)

EDIT: I now know you can't see the trade currency page without logging in with an account (Which is free). You can see an image [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/images/thumb/b/b3/Trade_Currency_2014.png/460px-Trade_Currency_2014.png) and a wiki page [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Currency_Exchange). I've decided to use Bubby4j's answer which supplied me with a helpful system that already did what I asked for. I now only need to fix it (As it may be outdated) and get it running on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually wrote a PHP script that does this. It uses MySQL to store the Trade Currency data.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c46wuzhf7636htc/AAALYLvzpbnBzK2qSjfybcGxa?dl=0

There's a zip of what I had. I don't know if it still works but it might be useful.

It even logs into Roblox automatically.

I used a cronjob every 5 seconds to trigger the script that recorded the current TC rates.

The included .sql file contains the structure of the database & some sample data.

You'll likely need to edit quite a few things to get it working, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've downloaded your work and set up a website where I will be trying to revive the outdated code. I do not know any SQL and I've only had an introduction to PHP so this project may take some time. You can see my current progress [here](http://www.tradetracker.tk/). I've only so far uploaded the old PHP/PHS files into public (For storage) and imported the SQL file into phpMyAdmin; I had to delete the previously logged info because the upload size max is 2MB.

Comment: You can actually upload bigger files if you use FTP. Let me know if you need any help! One thing to note is with that host I believe a cronjob can only run every 5 minutes or so. You won't be able to get data that's quite as granular. The MySQL username/password will need to go in roblox_tc_db.inc.php

Comment: The limit on the cronjob timing will prevent me from analyzing the patterns that appear in small instances, however I will still be able to track patterns over a day (Seeing when the highs and lows are) and over a year (Such as holiday boosts and such). Now that I think of it, I will also try to add a program that tracks when items are released so that the graph can compare sales/trades to released hats.

Comment: Sounds really cool @GShocked! Hope you enjoy it!

Comment: Which file(s) should I run a cronjob on?

Comment: I believe it's update_rates_database.php

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. Also, I would remove that dropbox download as it contains login information for your Roblox TCAPI account.

Comment: Didn't really care about the account, but I changed the password anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I decided to use Python to create the web-scraper because it seemed easier to learn; It was. I created a script that gets the first five TC rates and averages them (To give a more reasonable measurement). My Raspberry Pi is running the script on a 10 minute cron job. Flask is running my python webpage at 0.0.0.0:5000. I am port forwarding that page. RaspCTL is the dynamic DNS that I am using. http://tcserver.raspctl.com:5000/ is where the PUBLIC page is located. Mission accomplished. Now I need to start making Robux off of this.

Comment: Now Roblox made a useful api where you can get an estimated trade return, which makes my code a heck of a lot less. It avoids logging in and looking for the rates in the page. I will use a free web host for the server soon and make it in PHP. http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Web_APIs#Economy_APIs

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about the nature of roblox however what you describe here is called [web-crawling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler), thus in order to accomplish this, there is not a single language, most of them are suitable. what I would do first is check weather roblox provides any usable [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API)s which are there to help developers such as your self in fetching the data you need, in a more use friendly way such as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) which you can easily use in any language.
 in case an API is not available you can try to fetch the data as [plain text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) with various tools such as [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [text based web-browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser) in order to determine weather an html parser will suffice or the website requires something more advanced such as a [javascript interpeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine), and there are such, an headless browser such as [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)(also available for use commandline just like curl, with full js support). It is most preffered to limit yourself to just fetching the page, parsing the html and getting the data you need rather than using a full headless browser solution such as phantomjs as the latter has the potential to slow things down and is generally more complex.

for sake of simplicity, since you mentioned that your final result is to make a webserver which serves the data I would go the following way:

1. install a [lemp](https://www.google.com/search?q=lemp%20install%20guide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=EZqkVMOqEcqH8QfDlIDYBg)([linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) [mysql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) [php](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)) OR [lamp](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+install+lemp&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=zKSkVPu_MuSG8Qe2yYDgAg)([linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) [apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) [mysql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) [php](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)) stack. just download it into your linux box using your favourite package manager.
2. Since the final reault is a web server you might want to use php which comes out of the box in the packages I stated above:
   In case there is an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API), it gets as simple as fetching the page of the supported API and running [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)/[XML](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php) parse on it and using the data.
   but if there is no api
   First fetch the page in php using [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781876/get-file-content-via-php-curl#answer-12782109) or [file get contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) functions available in php, then try to parse the page with any HTML parsers available for PHP such as [SIMPLE DOM PARSER](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

The above steps are in case you don't need to go into the complexities of a full blown browser, but if you do, you should find comfort in phantomjs and try to use it [standalone(javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173928/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-website-with-phantomjs#answer-20174298) to fetch your data, or try to find a [php interface to communicate with phantomjs](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=php%20simple%20dom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5pykVNutO8mI8QfOt4D4Aw#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&q=php%20phantomjs%20class) in google. The steps are similar in their approach: fetch the page and parse the html in it in order to get the required data.

3. Since you already are in a webserver (lemp/lamp) you are in fact already able to preasent a webpage to your devices online. so simpley do step 2, save to the database(mysql) and generate a page matching your need. Note php runs only when the user loads the page on which it resides, therefore if you need periodic checks, just use [cron jobs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job#answer-2369) to [schedule tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url#answer-13259736) at certain times and re run your php scripts.

Note 1: the steps above are very general since you did not specify your background in this field.
These steps simply describe how web crawling works in general.

Note 2: If you wish to make your service accesible outside of your network, In order to do that you should configure(usually is the default) your webserver(lemp/lamp) at [port 80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_80) and then you should provide your users with your outside [ip address](http://duckip.info).
If your ip is dynamically changing you can use free services such as [NO-IP](http://www.noip.com/) or maybe [this](https://github.com/vasilevich/CloudflareUpdater).
there are other more complex solutions such as renting a domain name.